# Branch point of $\log(z)+arcsin(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-points

i try to do it by substituting $z$ into $\frac{1}{t}$. Then, it would become  this function $-iln[i+t\sqrt{(1-\frac{1}{t^2})}]$. Teacher says that when $z=z_\infty$ is a branch point, only could be that $f(z)$ isn't finite. However, i couldn't figure out.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean $i \ln z + \arcsin z$. As a multi-valued function,
$$i \ln z + \arcsin z =
\frac \pi 2 - i \ln \left( 1 + \sqrt {1 - \frac 1 {z^2}} \right).$$
From this it can be seen that there is an infinite number of sheets which are unbranched over $\infty$ (corresponding to the positive square root) but also an infinite number of sheets which are sequentially glued over $\infty$ (corresponding to the negative square root). There is still a logarithmic branch point at $\infty$ if you add any multiple of $\ln z$ to $\arcsin z$.

Finiteness isn't really relevant here; $1/\sqrt z$ has a branch point at $\infty$ and is bounded in a neighborhood of $\infty$.

Comment: i know that $\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{z^2}}$ can be taken different values. However, i wonder that if i take  $\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{z^2}}$  to be -1, then how could i show that this function is discontinuous when going around an arbitrarily small circuit around $z_\infty$.

Comment: Take the principal value of the square root. $1 - \sqrt {1 - 1/z^2}$ is regular and behaves like $1/(2 z^2)$ at infinity. Going once around a large circle counterclockwise subtracts $4 \pi$ from the value of the function.

Comment: why? i can't figure it out. Could you give me some hints since i have just learned complex analysis few weeks.

Comment: First you need to work out what happens with $\ln(1/(2 z^2))$ when you go around the origin. Then expand the square root into a power series around infinity to write the function as
$$\ln \left( \frac 1 {2 z^2} (1 + \ldots) \right) =
\ln \left( \frac 1 {2 z^2} \right) + \ln(1 + \ldots),$$
where the second part is regular at infinity.

Comment: Then, i think the latter function would just act like $\ln(1)$ since the latter one is infinite sum of powers of $\frac{1}{z^2}$.

Comment: Essentially, yes, it's $\ln z$ with $z$ sufficiently close to $1$, which makes the $\ln(1 + \ldots)$ part analytic on $|z| > R$ as a composition of analytic functions, it can't be multi-valued. It remains to show that $z = \infty$ is a branch point for $\ln(1/(2 z^2)) = -\ln 2 - 2 \ln z$.

Comment: i think i fully get it. thank for your help